# R: generate a matrix instead of a list

Tags: r

I have a very simple code that generates a training and testing set for K-fold cross validation.
I have a matrix **X**[20x15] and If I take the number of folds `n_folds` e.g. 10 I get a *matrix* : `trainingData`[18x15] and `testData`[2x15] which is correct.

Now, if I change the number of folds `n_folds=20`, I test a `trainingData`[19x15] which is correct, but for the `testData`, R generates a list, and not a matrix [1x15]. When I use the `as.matrix` function, it generates me a [15x1] matrix and not [1x15].

Here is the code for `n_fold=20`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
require(stats)
set.seed(19875)
n=20
p=15
real_p=15
x=matrix(rnorm(n*p), nrow=n, ncol=p)
n_folds=20
  #Randomly shuffle the data 
  x=x[sample(nrow(x)),]
  folds=cut(seq(1, nrow(x)), breaks = n_folds, labels = FALSE)
  #Perform 10 fold cross validation 
  for(i in 1:n_folds){
    #segment your data by folds using the which() function 
    testIndexes=which(folds==i, arr.ind = TRUE)
    testData=x[testIndexes,]
    trainData=x[-testIndexes,]
  }
```

What would be the simplest way to generate a matrix for the `testData` which would be a matrix [1x15] and not a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue here is that you are extracting the rows, and you only have one row, so you're getting a vector. To enforce a matrix, use a call to matrix. Your initial try with a call to matrix used the default way of constructing a matrix, which produces a single column. Specify what you want the columns and the rows to be. I've presumed you want the dimensions to be `length(testIndexes)` by `p`, but if it's something else, you can use this as the form of the correct answer. Just sub in what you want it to be.

```
set.seed(19875)
n=20
p=15
real_p=15
x=matrix(rnorm(n*p), nrow=n, ncol=p)
n_folds=20
#Randomly shuffle the data 
x=x[sample(nrow(x)),]
folds=cut(seq(1, nrow(x)), breaks = n_folds, labels = FALSE)
#Perform 10 fold cross validation 
for(i in 1:n_folds){
  #segment your data by folds using the which() function 
  testIndexes=which(folds==i, arr.ind = TRUE)
  testData=matrix(x[testIndexes,], length(testIndexes), p)
  trainData=x[-testIndexes,]
}
```

Comment: thank a lot, yes the dimensions are correct `length(testIndexes)`

Answer (score 1):

I re-wrote your code a bit and came up with this, I hope it is useful:

```
library ( dplyr )
library ( tidyr )
library ( stats )
library ( magrittr )

set.seed ( 19875 )

N <- 20
P <- 15

X <- matrix ( rnorm ( N * P ), N )
N_Folds <- 5

Folds <- rep ( 1:N_Folds, l = N ) %>% sample

for ( Fold in 1:N_Folds ){
  Validation <- which ( Fold == Folds )
  Valid_Data <- X [ Validation,, drop = FALSE ]
  Train_Data <- X [ -Validation,, drop = FALSE ]
}

Train_Data %>% dim
Valid_Data %>% dim
```

David